# Añadir archivos tipo _old y .bak en .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Estoy añadiendo archivos al `.gitignore` y me ha surgido una duda respecto a los `_old`:

Tengo archivos tipo `x_old.html`, `x_old.php`.

¿Cómo se debe indicar en el `.gitignore`? `*_old.*` u `_old` a secas?

Los archivos `.bak` supongo que aunque sean del tipo `x.html.bak` con `*.bak` serviría.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, debes utilizar la opción:

```
*_old.*
```

De este modo todos los archivos que coincidan con la expresión `*_old.*` serán ignorados.

Por contra, si dijeras `_old`, estaría buscando ficheros que se llamen exactamente "_old".

---

Mi truco es crear archivos de este tipo y luego por línea de comandos (en Linux, por ejemplo) ver si coinciden con el parámetro escrito en el fichero .gitignore:

```
$ touch x_old.html x_old.php

$ ls *_old.*
x_old.html  x_old.php

$ ls _old
ls: cannot access '_old': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, googleando me encontré un ejemplo en el que estaba directamente _old pero no me cuadraba si tenía que ser para todos los archivos, un saludo y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @dpfernandez10 me alegro que te ayudara :) Siempre es útil editar el `.gitignore` y a continuación mirar `git status` para ver si está funcionando o no.